# $x^{2}(x−1)^{2}(x^2+1)+y^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[x,y].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Why $x^{2}(x−1)^{2}(x^2+1)+y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

I tried to do it directly, but I have problems. Could anyone give me an hint? I don't want a solution. I think it's very easy, but at this moment I have problem to claim it.

Comment: If it had a factorisation, it would have one of the form $(y+f(x))(y+g(x))$.

Comment: Yes, I tried just like that. And we have that $f(x)=-g(x)$ and $f(x)g(x)=x^2(x-1)^2(x^2+1).$ But I can't see contradiction, which is trivial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, but why in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Comment: This is now an equation in $\Bbb C[x]$. Has it a solution there?

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}[x]$ $f(x)$ factors into linear terms and since $f(x)=-g(x)$, $g(x)$ is product of this linear terms with minus before product. So $f(x)g(x)$ has even power of this term in product, but right side has power equal $1$ in factor $(x+i)$ in factorization of right side, so it hasn't solution. I'm right?

Comment: That's right: $x+i$ only occurs once.

Comment: So it is easy in fact. Thanks!